# clean "prefixes" in a set of arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays, set, prefix

I was wondering, I've got a Set of Arrays containing something of my own datatype.
something looking like:

```
traces = {[<label1>, <label2>], [<label1>], [<label1>,<label2>,<label3>]}
```

Now, I would like to have a method that cleans all 'prefix'-existing arrays in the Set, 
so my new set will be in this example:

```
traces = {[<label1>,<label2>,<label3>]}
```

Anybody an idea how to make a clean implementation out of this?
I hope there is a neater solution than stepping through traces and a Set new_traces and comparing every array-item several times.

Note: 
I define Array A is a prefix of Array B iff the first items of Array B are actually the Array A

Comment: You're not clear. Do you want to remove  two first arrays or you want to return uniq labels? And why do you use Hash of Arrays... `{[], [], []}` you should use Array of Arrays: `[[],[],[]]`

Comment: I guess you should flatten then call uniq and recreate an array. http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000762

Comment: sorry for not being clear, I use the hashes since its a Set of Arrays, because I have unique arrayitems and the order the arrays are in do not matter. Hope this clears it a bit up, if not, please let me know

Comment: If you're using a set, then why not use a [Set?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html)

Comment: it isn't clear what do you want to do :) what do you want to remove?

Comment: by set I meant Set, I just changed it, sorry for the ambiguity.
I don't see how flatten can help me directly

Comment: fl00r,I would like to remove all the arrays in the set that are prefix of other arrays in the set.
with prefix I mean that they are shorter than another array, but contain the same first elements, just like in the example

Comment: what should this return? `{[<label1>, <label2>], [<label1>], [<label1>,<label2>,<label3>], [<label1>, <label5>], [<label1>,<label2>,<label6>], [<label2>, <label1>]}`

Comment: thanks for the effort fl00r, it should return:
`{[<label1>,<label2>,<label3>], [<label1>, <label5>], [<label1>,<label2>,<label6>], [<label2>, <label1>]}`

Comment: what Ruby version do you use?

Comment: 1.8, from Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite the fastest solution, but rather simple:

```
s = Set.new([[1,2],[1],[1,2,3]])
s.reject{|prefix|
  s.any?{|array|
    array.length > prefix.length && array[0,prefix.length] == prefix
  }
}
#=>[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks both of you! 
this was exactly what I needed, I know Ruby had some tricks that I didnt know yet to help me here :)

Comment: Nice! I always forget to look at solutions in enumerable

Answer (score 0):

call flatten and then uniq

```
 class T
  attr_accessor :n
  def initialize(n); @n = n; end
  def eql?(other); n.eql?(other.n); end
  def hash; n.hash; end
end

a = [T.new(1), T.new(2), T.new(3), T.new(4), T.new(2), T.new(1), [T.new(2), T.new(2)], [T.new(4)]]

a.flatten.uniq.map(&:n) # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: its not about duplicates and the arrayitems are not the problem

Comment: Sorry but this still isn't what i meant, your example in my case would be somthing where
a is a Set of Arrays
and the result should be `{[1], [3], [4], [2,2,4]}` (clearing the prefix-clones)